# Run same method of each derived type sequentially c#

Tags: c#, abstract-class, derived-class, base-class

I have below code with `IVehicle` interface having `TestDrive` method.
There is an abstract class - `Vehicles`, which implements `IVehicle` & has a property `TestDriveTime`.

There are a number of child classes like `Car`, `Scooter`, etc (about 25 such child classes). which derive from `Vehicle` & have their own implementations of `TestDrive()`.

Please help me with my questions -

1. If I have to run each of these `TestDrive` sequentially, is my code in `Main()` correct?
2. If All the child objects are using the same `TestDriveTime`, how shall I set it?

.

```
public interface IVehicle 
{  
    void TestDrive();
}

public abstract class Vehicle : IVehicle
{
    public DateTime TestDriveTime { get; set; }
    abstract public void TestDrive();
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public override void TestDrive()
    {
        // code for car testDrive
        // uses TestDriveTime
    }
}

public class Scooter : Vehicle
{
    public override void TestDrive()
    {
        // code for car testDrive
        // uses TestDriveTime same as car
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IVehicle vehicle = null;
    // 1. need to set the TestDriveTime which can be used for vehicles of all types. 

    vehicle = new Car();        
    vehicle.TestDrive();

    // 2. Need to run the TestDrive for all vehicles sequentially

    vehicle = new Scooter();
    vehicle.TestDrive();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Declare a list:

```
List<IVehicle> vehicles = new List<IVehicle>();
```

then add all of your vehicles:

```
vehicles.Add(new Car());
vehicles.Add(new Scooter());
```

and iterate:

```
        foreach (IVehicle v in vehicles)
            v.TestDrive();
```

2) You can set TestDriveTime and use it for all of your objects:

v.TestDrive(TestDriveTime);

Change the method declaration to: `IVehicle.TestDrive(DateTime testDriveTime)`